# .htaccess RewriteRule country codes as a get param

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I want to achieve:

> http://example.com/en -> http://example.com/?lang=en
>
> http://example.com/en/something -> http://example.com/something/?lang=en
>
> http://example.com/ru -> http://example.com/?lang=ru
>
> http://example.com/ru/something -> http://example.com/something/?lang=ru

I try with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^en/(.+)$ /?p=$1&lang=en [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ru/(.+)$ /?p=$1&lang=ru [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(ru|en)/(.+)$ /$2/?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(ru|en)/?$ /?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`(ru|en)` will match either `ru` or `en`. If you wanted to make it a generic 2 letter match, you could use `[a-z]{2}`

Comment: This work, but how to achieve without redirect ? I want still have `http://example.com/en` but also get lang params.